# Rodapé fixo no fundo da página

Tags: html, css, footer

Bom, já procurei em vários sites como posso fazer isto maioria fala que é pra eu por

```
body, html{height:100%;}
footer{width:100%; bottom:0; position:absolute;}
```

Mas quando eu faço isso, ele fica no fundo da tela, e não no final da página.

Ou seja, ele fica no meio e se sobrepondo ao conteúdo.

Alguém tem sabe como posso deixa-lo fixo?

Estou trabalhando da seguinte maneira. Separa um arquivo "Header.php", "Footer.php", e depois incluo no arquivo de conteúdo

```
<?php include "header.php"?>
//conteudo
...
<?php include "footer.php" ?>
```

Comment: Boa tarde, poste a estrutura html, pois senão é impossível saber o que exatamente causou o problema, tente por enquanto isto: `footer{width:100%; bottom:0; position:absolute; z-index: 500;}`.

Answer (score 0):

Para fixar no html é usado o fixed do pasition no caso seu código seria:

```
body {
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px;
}

footer {
    width:100%; 
    position:fixed; 
    left 0px; 
    bottom:0px;
}
```

Com isso ele fica fixo no final da tela.